# WebAPI - HTTP405: BAD METHOD - The HTTP verb used is not supported using JavaScript

Tags: c#, ajax, webapi

I'm posting to my Web API on Azure from a remote webpage. I use the following:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: BaseHref + "/api/PIRknownPersons/",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function (response) {
            //alert('Saved known ');
        },
        error: function (e) {
             //alert('Unable to save Known ' );
        }
    });
```

I could be wrong but it looks like remote posting is blocked on Azure as the code works fine when I do it locally. Is this the case? Is there a setting on Azure that I can turn off?

PIRknownPersons -

```
namespace TripWeb.Controllers
{
    public class PIRknownPersonsController : ApiController
    {
        private TripDB3Entities db = new TripDB3Entities();

        // POST: api/PIRknownPersons
        [ResponseType(typeof(bool))]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]ApiPIRknownPerson APIPIRknownPerson)
        {
            var inst = db.Institutions.Where(x => x.RemoteID == APIPIRknownPerson.RemoteID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (inst == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Action Not Authorized");
            }

            var newPIRknownPerson = ObjectMapper.GetEfApiPIRknownPerson(APIPIRknownPerson);

            try
            {
                db.PIRknownPersons.Add(newPIRknownPerson);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're getting a 405 back from the server - verify that you're not hitting a `GET` (or any type other than `POST`) endpoint?

Comment: Show us the code for the `PIRknownPersons` action.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Added code as requested

Comment: what's your webapi routing config?

Comment: Forgive me - not sure where I would get that? For what its worth the API works fine when the post is coming from the same server

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - or at least I got it working. I did two things:

- Enabled CORS on Azure through the control panel
- Appended `[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]` to the top of my controller files.

Don't know if both are needed but it works now anyway.